# c# convert string to single

Tags: c#, .net-1.1

i have a program running for a while and everything works fine till this weird thing happens. when i convert a number string to Single, i just can't get the value i want. for example:

`Convert.ToSingle("11006.954")` return the value 11006.9541
`Convert.ToSingle("20678.228")` return the value 20678.2285

I know i can fix it using Convert.ToDouble but it will take days to modify the existing system. I am using vs2003 .net 1.1.

Comment: [Here's why](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You seem to be expecting a `Single` to be able to represent *exactly* the numbers you've given. It can't. 11006.9541 is the closest `Single` value to 11006.954. (In fact, the *exact* value of the closest `Single` is 11006.9541015625, but I suspect you're seeing 11006.9541 in the debugger.)

If you want accurate representations of numbers originally expressed as decimals, you should use `System.Decimal`.

See my articles on [binary floating point](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx) and [decimal floating point](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Decimal.aspx) in .NET for further information.

Comment: thank you. this really helps. looks like i am making a newbie mistake :p